# Does Singleton class with its instance as volatile make the instance data to be load again?

Tags: java, synchronization, singleton, volatile

In my application Server class is load on startup and all data is cached as once.

It is a singleton class ,and its instance variable is not volatile
i.e.

```
private static Server server;
```

After findbug analysis, i have to change it to volatile,(shown below

```
public class Server {
    private static volatile Server server;

    public static Server getInstance(){
        if(server == null){
            synchronized (Server .class) {
                if(server == null){
                    try {
                        server = new Server(....);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Logger.logError(MODULE, "IO Error while creating server home location: " + strServerHome);
                        Logger.logTrace(MODULE, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return server;
    }.......
}
```

but after reading articles and Q/A about volatile on stack, i think volatile will make the data to be load again ,as volatile make information to be read from memory and not cache.

***So should i make my variable volatile or not ?***

***if volatile , then do i have to load my data again & again ?***

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: i completely agree with it but does that mean i have to load data again as my server instance is volatile

Comment: No, your understanding of volatile is completely wrong! volatile just specifies how threads can use a field, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally considered safest method to create a thread-safe singleton is make it an enum...

```
 public enum Server{
      INSTANCE;

      public Server getInstance(){
          return INSTANCE;
      }

      private Server(){...}

      // rest of methods here
 }
```

[Singleton:The Enum Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum_way)

Comment: But then it's not lazy, isn't it?

Comment: It will be loaded the first time the class is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - without `volatile`, you've got the infamous 'double checked locking' antipattern which is not thread safe (even if it seems so). (Even with volatile it would not be thread safe with Java versions prior to Java 5).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

But although its thread safe with `volatile` and Java >=5, its ugly code, so you should either write a simple `synchronized` `getInstance` method...

```
public static synchronized Server getInstance() {
    if (server == null) server = new Servier(...);
    return server;
}
```

...or use the initializer on demand holder pattern:

```
private static class ServerHolder {
    public static Server server = new Server(...);
}

public static Server getInstance() {
    return ServerHolder.server;
}
```

Because class `ServerHolder` is loaded lazily on its first usage, class initialization will happen when `getInstance` is called for the first time, and so, `Server` will be instantiated lazily.

Comment: but do i have to load my data again, as i don't want the same to be done.

Comment: What data? I don't understand. The first example does not differ from yours except that it is thread safe (and simpler). The second is just an elegant variation.